# Comparing svd and princomp in R

Tags: r, pca, svd

I want to get `singular values of a matrix in R` to get the principal components, then make princomp(x) too to compare results

I know princomp() would give the principal components

**Question**

How to get the principal components from  $d, $u, and $v (solution of  `s = svd(x)` )?

Comment: I rolled back this edit, since adding MYasseen's (good) answer wasn't necessary; I flagged your other question to be merged with this one, so hopefully both answers will be here shortly.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

One way or another, you should probably look into `prcomp`, which calculates PCA using `svd` instead of `eigen` (as in `princomp`). That way, if all you want is the PCA output, but calculated using `svd`, you're golden.

Also, if you type `stats:::prcomp.default` at the command line, you can see how it's using the output of `svd` yourself.